# Laravel 4, how to send different flash messages depending on users credentials and hidden input

Tags: authentication, laravel, laravel-4, message

I am trying to check the status of a users account when the user logs into the application with Laravel 4.1.

```
$attempt = Auth::attempt(array('email' => $input['email'], 'password' => $input['password'], 'active'
=> $input['active']), true);

if($attempt) return Redirect::route('photos.index');

return Redirect::back()->withInput()->with('message', 'Your email or password are incorrect.');
```

I am using a hidden input "active" to check whether a user account is still active or not. This works fine. However, if this check fails, the user gets to see the same flash message that is displayed when he enters wrong credentials. How could I send a second flash message that states to the user that his account is not active anymore even if he had entered correct credentials?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the `Auth::attempt()` fails you can check with this if it succeeded without an active account.

```php
$attempt = Auth::attempt(array('email' => $input['email'], 'password' => $input['password'], 'active'
=> $input['active']), true);

if($attempt) return Redirect::route('photos.index');

// Check if credentials are correct but the account is not active
if (Auth::validate(array('email' => $input['email'], 'password' => $input['password'])))
{
    // Valid but not active
    return Redirect::back()->withInput()->with('message', 'Account not active.');
}

return Redirect::back()->withInput()->with('message', 'Your email or password are incorrect.');
```

Comment: One thing. Could you just briefly explain to me the difference between Auth::attempt and Auth::validate?

Comment: `Auth::validate` will only validate the login. It doesn't remember the user is logged in. `Auth::attempt` will keep the user logged in so you can use `Auth::check()` and `Auth::user()`